# Calculate the difference between two timestamps in bash

Tags: bash, date

I want to find out total system boot time by subtracting two timestamps. 
First I use this command to get the start time and end time:

```
sudo journalctl | grep "Logs begin at" | awk '{print $6" "$7" "$12" "$13}'
```

which gets me the following output:

```
2020-05-21 05:52:47 2020-05-28 19:37:36
```

(The first two fields being the start time and the last two fields being the end time)

Now I want to find the difference between the start time and end time, preferably in the format:

"0 year(s), 0 month(s), 7 day(s), HH:MM:SS"

Comment: could you get the output as "2020-05-21 05:52:47;2020-05-28 19:37:36"?

Comment: Yes, then I would use the command `sudo journalctl | grep "Logs begin at" | awk '{print $6" "$7";"$12" "$13}'`

Comment: which bash version are you using?

Comment: version 5.0.3(1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about this?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "BASH_VERSION:" $BASH_VERSION 

line="2020-05-21 05:52:47;2020-05-28 19:37:36"
IFS=';' read -a dates <<< $line
startDatetime=${dates[0]}
endDatetime=${dates[1]}

echo "| dates -> " ${dates[@]}
echo "|> startDatetime -> ${startDatetime}"
echo "|> endDatetime -> ${endDatetime}"

startTime=$(date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "${startDatetime}" +%s)
endTime=$(date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "${endDatetime}" +%s)
diffSeconds="$(($endTime-$startTime))"

echo "Diff in seconds: $diffSeconds"
# at this point you have the diff in seconds and you can parse it however you want :)

diffTime=$(gdate -d@${diffSeconds} -u +%H:%M:%S) # you'll need `brew install coreutils`
echo "Diff time(H:M:S): $diffTime"
```

Output:

```
BASH_VERSION: 5.0.17(1)-release
| dates ->  2020-05-21 05:52:47 2020-05-28 19:37:36
|> startDatetime -> 2020-05-21 05:52:47
|> endDatetime -> 2020-05-28 19:37:36
Diff in seconds: 654289
Diff time(H:M:S): 13:44:49
```

To install the latest `bash` I found [this medium post](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba).

Note: If this doesn't work because some version incompatibilities with the `date` function, for example, the idea should be pretty similar and you could find a workaround that adapts to your current version, I'm sure. Logically, the easiest solution I see is:

1st) Split the string into two: one for each DateTimes.

2nd) Transform each DateTime from string to dates.

3rd) Apply a diff between these dates: using the seconds from each.

4th) Having the diff seconds you can display it as you want (year, days, minutes, seconds)

Comment: Thanks for this :) This worked for me. Now I have a follow up question, which is, what if I have a list of my last say, 10, boots which I save in a file I call runtime.txt after running this command: `sudo journalctl | grep "Logs begin at" | awk '{print $6" "$7";"$12" "$13}' | tee runtime.txt` And I want to take the lines in that file and use them as arguments for  your script which I named datediff.sh? Also I changed the first line of your script to say: `line="$1"` so that it can read in an argument when I invoke the script. (ie. `./datediff.sh "2020-05-21 05:52:47;2020-05-28 19:37:36"`

Comment: Basically, I don't want to keep copy/pasting each runtime of multiple boots, which is why I am saving it in a file called runtime.txt

Comment: Actually, I figured it out on my own. Thanks again for the script!

Comment: I just saw your response. I'm happy to hear that, you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 5):

Same version as @chemaclass but this time for Ubuntu (16.04 LTS).

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "BASH_VERSION:" $BASH_VERSION 

line="2020-05-21 05:52:47;2020-05-28 19:37:36"
IFS=';' read -a dates <<< $line
startDatetime=${dates[0]}
endDatetime=${dates[1]}

echo "| dates -> " ${dates[@]}
echo "|> startDatetime -> ${startDatetime}"
echo "|> endDatetime -> ${endDatetime}"


startTime=$(date -d "${startDatetime}" +%s)
endTime=$(date -d "${endDatetime}" +%s)
diffSeconds="$(($endTime-$startTime))"

echo "Diff in seconds: $diffSeconds"
# at this point you have the diff in seconds and you can parse it however you want :)

diffTime=$(date -d @${diffSeconds} +"%H:%M:%S" -u)
echo "Diff time(H:M:S): $diffTime"
```

Output:

```sh
BASH_VERSION: 5.0.0(1)-release
| dates ->  2020-05-21 05:52:47 2020-05-28 19:37:36
|> startDatetime -> 2020-05-21 05:52:47
|> endDatetime -> 2020-05-28 19:37:36
Diff in seconds: 654289
Diff time(H:M:S): 13:44:49
```

I updated the bash to version 5.0.0 following [this tutorial](https://www.ramoonus.nl/2019/01/08/bash-5-0-installation-for-linux/).
With the default bash version (4.4.20) doesn't work.
You will get an error message like: `redirection unexpected` on line 3 because of the `<<<` symbol.

Comment: `$(date -d @${diffSeconds} +"%H:%M:%S" -u)` What does -u do?

Comment: You can find the explanation with `man date` command → `print or set Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)`

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be

```
#!/bin/bash

strSTARTTIME="2020-05-21 05:52:47"
strENDTIME="2020-05-28 19:37:36"

STARTTIME=$(date -d "${strSTARTTIME}" +%s)
ENDTIME=$(date -d "${strENDTIME}" +%s)

RUNTIME=$((ENDTIME-STARTTIME))

echo "Seconds ${RUNTIME} in sec"
```

Further calculation and formatting I'll leave at your side.